# Split with multiple delimiters and swap words using awk

Tags: awk

How can I split string with multiple delimiters and then swap words based on few conditions -

From string - (delimiter is _ and string can vary with any kind of words, not just string starting with ocs)

```
'customer_document_map_ocsumm2','customer_ocsumm1','session_detail_ocsumm2'
```

To string -

```
'ocsumm2.customer_document_map'::regclass,'ocsumm1.customer'::regclass,'ocsumm2.session_detail'::regclass
```

I tried with my minimal knowledge on awk with below code but in vain, since I do not know how to store the results after each split and then derive back the desired result -

```
awk 'BEGIN {
split($0,ary,",");
for(ele in ary){
    split(ele,ary2,"_")
    owner=ary2[$NF]     
}
print owner }'
```

Comment: probably simpler with sed: `echo "$string"|sed -E "s/'([^']+)_([^']+)'(,|$)/'\2_\1'::regclass\3/g"`

Comment: you've tagged the question with `awk`; please update the question with the `awk` code you've tried and the (wrong) result generated by your code

Comment: please update the question with a textual description of what you're trying to do; for example, it's not clear if we're supposed to look for a string that starts with `ocs` or if we're to look for the last `_`-delimited field (which just happens to be two strings that start with `ocs`)

Comment: @markp-fuso Apologies for ambiguity, I have updated the question with my vague knowledge on awk. Also the suggestion from jhnc using sed produces desired result but for my curiosity and learning purpose I just want to know how to do it in awk.

Comment: `echo "$string"|awk '{for(f=2;f<NF;f++){n=split($f,a,"_");s="\047"a[n];for(i=1;i<n;i++)s=s"_"a[i];$(f-1)=s"\047::regclass"}}NF-=2' FS="[',]+" OFS=,` - assumes input is valid, add error checks around `split` if not

Comment: `$0` isn't populated in a `BEGIN` section since `$0` contains the most recent record read from the input while the `BEGIN` section is executed before any input is read. So remove the keyword `BEGIN` as a starting point.